# Problem with quadratic distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $a >0$ , $ f_a:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ with $f_a= \frac{2x}{a}e^{-x^2/a}$ Let $X_a$ be a related random variable. I want to calculate the distribution $X_a^2$. Since I know $f_a$ is a pdf. I tried this:
$$F_p(x)= \int_{-\infty}^t \! f_a(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^t \! \frac{2x}{a}e^{-x^2/a} \, \mathrm{d}x =-e^{-t^2/a}.$$
$\Rightarrow \mathbb P(X_a \le -e^{-t^2/a}) $.

$\Rightarrow$$\mathbb P(X_a^2 \le -e^{-t^2/a})=\mathbb P(-\sqrt{-e^{-t^2/a}}) \le X_a \le \sqrt{-e^{-t^2/a}})$

Of course my last line is heavily wrong(root etc.).
I think my mistake happens while I go from $X_a$ to $X_a^2$. 
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cdf does not seem correct...Here is the cdf

$$\begin{array}{cc}
F(x)= \left\{  
\begin{array}{cc}
 1-e^{-\frac{x^2}{a}} & x>0 \\
 0 & \text{Otherwise} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\right.
\end{array}$$

Then, given

$$f(x)=\frac{2 x e^{-\frac{x^2}{a}}}{a}$$

with domain of support given by $\{x,\ 0,\ \infty \}$, the new 
random variable

$$Y = X^2$$

is given by

$$f(y) = \frac{e^{-\frac{y}{a}}}{a}$$

with domain of support $\{y\ ,0,\ \infty \}$

You can verify that $f(y)$ is a proper density by showing

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{y}{a}}}{a} \, dy = 1$$,

which it does.